# Populate a Power BI table based on a dynamically ranked list that is from another table

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, dax, powerbi-custom-visuals, ranking-functions

We are a sales company and want to find a way to populate a Power BI table with data for a given set of accounts that is dynamically ranked based on other filters. Is essence, we have the "by month" table that will be seen and have the sales data and then an account Rank table.

Is there  way to populate the "by month" table with the account sales data that is rank 1 (or2 or 3) in the second table, dynamically. Our other filters on the document are things like our products and our states. So, there are separate account lists/ rankings based on the individual sets of filters.

In excel it is easily done with cell references etc. But we are stumped on the way in Power BI.

The attached picture is how we have "worked around the problem" for now, but want to be able to see the top 5 accounts stacked and changed based on the filters at the top of the page. As you can see in the picture, there is the by month table that changes as you select an account from the "rank" tables below it.
[Our work around currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvehb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select your Table/Matrix visual, and in the far right Filter pane, under `Filters for this visual` at the top, expand the `Account` card.
2. Change the Filter type to `Top N`,
3. Show items: select `Top` and `5`.
4. By value: select your Sales column/measure.
5. Click on `Apply filter` at the bottom.

You can refer to [Power BI – Top N filters](https://powerbidocs.com/2020/01/21/power-bi-top-n-filters/) for a more visual guide.